# How to run Minecraft for windows 10 in multiple accounts?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, xbox-network, windows-10

I've got a new windows 10 machine and installed the new Minecraft beta for windows 10. In my Linux machine, all the accounts play with the same Minecraft user (I have two sons). But in windows 10 it looks like each machine account is attached to one email address and to one Xbox live account. Each son has one email, but the license was bought with my email.

Is it possible to have all of my windows accounts using the same Minecraft account?

Comment: I think that licenses may be tied to the account (meaning that no other account can use said app without owning them). **This is a guess**, so I'll investigate it when I get back onto my main computer.

Comment: This is the answer I don't want to get :-) I've bought it with my email, since I have to fix when they forget the password. I also just have one computer, so when one is playing the other isn't. If everybody have to play using my account, I won't be able to use windows 10 nice family features

Comment: Actually.. I wonder - Is the Xbox logins tied to the online passport...?